# Strict aliasing rule with incompatible but same structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, strict-aliasing

Does this code violate strict aliasing rule? Why or why not?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STRUCT struct {int x; char y;}
typedef STRUCT my_struct_t;

void get(my_struct_t *data, int *x, char *y)
{
    *x = data->x;
    *y = data->y;
}

int main(void)
{
    STRUCT *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    data->x=100;
    data->y=55;

    int x;
    char y;
    get((my_struct_t*)data, &x, &y);

    return 0;
}
```

Since structs are not compatible because they don't share a tag my guess would be that this code violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: data is already a my_struct_t pointer so there's no need to re-cast it. I don't see where there are any aliasing violations. There could be alignment issues however. It would be better to declare data as STRUCT data; You allocate it dynamically but don't free it. It will free itself when the program terminates, but it's good practice to put in the free anyway as the code may be changed later and someone might forget to free it. Not that it's a big deal in this example.

Comment: @SimonGoater `I do not see` is not a very good assurance. C standard is the only source of information, not someones opinion

Comment: @0___________ Ask C standard then.

Comment: Code compiles with gcc tags -Wall -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 without issuing any warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure pointer `data` is pointing to a different type from `my_struct_t` because you have `struct { … } *data = …;` in `main()` (after macro expansion), and each time you have `struct { … }`, you are defining a new type distinct from any other type, even if those structure types have the same members.

C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶8](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p8) says:

> The presence of a *struct-declaration-list* in a *struct-or-union-specifier* declares a new type, within a translation unit.

The italicized terms are part of the syntax of the structure (and union) grammar.

Consequently, you are casting between types with the call

```
get((my_struct_t*)data, &x, &y);
```

In theory, that means undefined behaviour.  In practice, it will work with almost any compiler.

I tried using both GCC 11.2.0 and Apple Clang 14.0.0 with extensive options on your code, which I changed to specify `static` before the definition of `get()` to avoid errors for "no previous prototype for 'get'":

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
      -fno-common -pedantic -pedantic-errors -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=2 \
      -c sa43.c
$ clang -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
        -fno-common -pedantic -Weverything -Wno-nullability-extension \
        -Wno-nullability-completeness -pedantic-errors -fstrict-aliasing \
        -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -c sa43.c
$
```

The `-Weverything` flag for Clang triggers complaints about padding (`-Wpadded`, could be suppressed by `-Wno-padded`).  That then exposes a complaint about using `/usr/local/include` because of `-Wpoison-system-directories`.  The Clang `-Weverything` option is not all that helpful because it activates too many warnings, but adding `-Wno-poison-system-directories` (as well as `-Wno-padded`) allows the code to compile cleanly.

The `-Wno-nullability-extension` and `-Wno-nullability-completeness` are an extremely irritating necessity because otherwise the system headers fail horribly on my MacBook Pro running macOS Monterey 12.6.3.

So, de facto, your code is OK — but de jure, you are casting between different types.

Comment: Re “In practice, it will work with almost any compiler”: This particular code may, but we should not conclude any code with aliasing violation like this will “work.” E.g., consider a function in another translation unit taking pointers to two differently tagged but otherwise identical structures. The compiler might conclude the two pointers it receives point to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Constructs such as yours are allowed in *conforming C programs*, but not *strictly conforming C programs*.  In discussing the distinction, the authors of the Standard noted:

> A *strictly conforming program* is another term for a maximally portable program. The goal is to give the programmer a *fighting chance* to make powerful C programs that are also highly portable, without seeming to demean perfectly useful C programs that happen not to be portable, thus the adverb *strictly*.

The Standard deliberately gives implementations which are intended to serve narrowly specialized purposes broad latitude to behave in whatever ways would best serve those purposes, even at the expense of being unsuitable for everything else.  Because there are *some* programs that don't need such such constructs, and the performance of *those* programs could be improved if compilers didn't have to accommodate them, the C99 Standard waives jurisdiction over the question of which implementations should be expected to support such constructs.

The clang and gcc optimizers will process constructs which pass pointers to structure types which are defined at the point of use meaningfully if invoked with the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag, but should not be expected to do so reliably if invoked without that flag.  If defining structure types at the point of use will make it practical to do something that would otherwise more difficult, one should use a compiler configuration that supports such a construct, rather than jumping through hoops to be compatible even with implementations *specialized exclusively for tasks where such constructs would not be useful*.  Not only would jumping through hoops often make code harder to read, but it can also cause unexpected compiler behaviors which would not have occurred in code written for the `-fno-strict-aliasing` dialect.  For example, trying to make a function accept pointers to multiple structure types interchangeably by casting the passed address a union of involved structure types may fail if different structures have different alignment requirements, *even the passed pointer satisfies the alignment requirements of all the structure types that are actually be used*.